# how to delete top Activity in the back stack android

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

say this is my back stack content :

Main => Level1 => Level2 => Level3

**Main is the root**

I want to start the Level2 Activity again  but before that delete the Level3(top of the back stack)

Here my desired model after started myActivity

Main => Level1 => Level2 => Level2

how can i approach ?

Comment: Show the code  where you are navigate the activity Level3 to myActivity.

Comment: that's the point ! i just asked it :) @shahid17june

Answer (score 0):

You can easily clean up the Level3 Activity with finish().

In your Level3 activity:

```
startActivity(intent); //start myActivity
finish();
```

Comment: finish is not the optimize way , because i want to perform some animation along with going through activities

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code may be your problem will solve.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Level3.this, myActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent

Comment: thanks but it's not , say I have A B C in the back stack , i want to go from C to B but the B must be at the top , A -> B -> C  , Desired:  A -> B -> B
however your approach is going to implement this : A->B